# Find the properties of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}$

Tags: summation

I have to show that $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k} = \begin{cases} 1\ \text{if}\ n=0 \\ 0\ \text{if}\ n>0 \end{cases}$$

**My try:** I have tried to use snake oil method 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}$$ $$=\sum_m{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}}x^m$$ $$={\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \binom{m+1}{k}\sum_m\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}}x^m$$ We know that the second sum $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+n-k}}=\sum_m\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}x^m$ 
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+n-k}}$$$$=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+n}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}(1+x)^k$$ How should I proceed after that?

**Edit:** My method might be absolutely wrong so if anyone might show me some other method I would really appreciate it

Comment: 1) What is $\sum_m$? 2) If $m<n$ I think the last sum doesn't exist in closed form, 3) How did you get $x$ in the sum over $m$?

Comment: @Alex By $\sum_{m}$ I mean sum over all $m$.And I have also edited the question

Comment: I'm curious about a combinatorial proof of this statement, and so I've started a question to that end here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794539/combinatorial-proof-of-a-certain-alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients?lq=1

Comment: @Albas: Hint: It is not valid to factor out $\binom{m+1}{k}$,  since  this binomial coefficient depends on the inner sum with index $m$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Does that mean it will be better to take $n$ as the free variable here?

Comment: @Albas: When checking this problem again, I saw that the *snake oil method* does also work. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for snake oil here. Just negate the upper index using this identity:

$$\binom{r}{j} = (-1)^j \binom{j-r-1}{j},\quad \text{integer }j.$$

We get

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k} = (-1)^n\sum_k \binom{m+1}{k}\binom{-m-1}{n-k}.$$

Now this is just a Vandermonde convolution: the result is

$$(-1)^n\binom{(m+1)+(-m-1)}{n} = (-1)^n\binom{0}{n}.$$

Done. This is $0$ for $n > 0$ and $1$ for $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* Here we show that the *snake oil method* which was applied by OP does also work.

Let $S_m(n)$ denote the series
\begin{align*}
S_m(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}\qquad\qquad m,n\geq 0
\end{align*}

> The following is valid for $m\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> S_m(n)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1\qquad&\qquad n=0\\
> 0\qquad &\qquad n>0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_m(n)x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}x^n\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{m+n}{n}x^n\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=(1-x)^{m+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-(m+1)}{n}(-1)^nx^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(1-x)^{m+1}}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\tag{4}\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange the sums and factor out which does not depend on the inner sum.
- In (2) we shift the index $n$ of the inner sum so that it starts from $0$. We factor out $x^k$ (from $x^{n+k}$) and observe the sums are now separated.
- In (3) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)* to the left-hand sum and use the identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and the result is $1+0x+0x^2+\cdots$

Comment: +1 As I had written in the comments I had the feeling that I should have taken $n$ as the free variable. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Albas: And you was right! :-) You're welcome.