# Combinatorial proof of a certain alternating sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, combinatorial-proofs

The following identity appeared as a question earlier [today](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794450/137524)

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{m+n-k}{n-k} = \begin{cases} 1\ \text{if}\ n=0 \\ 0\ \text{if}\ n>0 \end{cases}$$

and was given an algebraic solution. **Is there a combinatorial proof?**

Comment: That the sum alternates suggests that some kind of inclusion-exclusion interpretation, but I don't know how to provide such a construction.

Comment: For reference: this is exercise 19 in section 1.4 "The Binomial Theorem" of *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Ivan Niven et al.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that you want to choose $n$ integers from the set $[m+n]$ in such a way that you do not include any integer less than or equal to $m+1$. If $n=0$ this is possible in exactly one way: you choose the empty set. If $n>0$, it’s not possible, since only the $n-1$ integers in $[m+n]\setminus[m+1]$ are available to be chosen.

For each $k\in[m+1]$ let $\mathscr{A}_k$ be the set of $n$-element subsets of $[m+n]$ that contain $k$; we want the number of $n$-element subsets of $[m+n]$ that are not in $\bigcup_{k\in[m+1]}\mathscr{A}_k$. Clearly

$$\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\right|=\binom{m+n-|I|}{n-|I|}$$

whenever $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[m+1]$, so by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) we have

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k\in[m+1]}\mathscr{A}_k\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[m+1]}(-1)^{|I|-1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\right|\\
&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[m+1]}(-1)^{|I|-1}\binom{m+n-|I|}{n-|I|}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m+1}k\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and hence the number of $n$-element subsets of $[m+n]$ that are not in $\bigcup_{k\in[m+1]}\mathscr{A}_k$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{m+n}n&-\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m+1}k\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\binom{m+n}n+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(-1)^k\binom{m+1}k\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}(-1)^k\binom{m+1}k\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}(-1)^k\binom{m+1}k\binom{m+n-k}{n-k}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=0\\
0,&\text{if }n>0\;.
\end{cases}$$

The fact that I have $m+1$ instead of $n$ as the upper limit of summation is unimportant: in both versions we’re simply summing over all values of $k$ for which the terms are non-zero.

Comment: I may be mistaken about this, but do you want $\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\right|=\binom{m+n-l}{n-l}$ where $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[m+1]$ with $|I|=l$?

Comment: @user84413: Good catch; thanks!

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user84413: You're welcome!